# Unclear step in solving the scalar potential equation for a line of infinite charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

Starting with the scalar potential function, my professor was demonstrating how to use it to solve for a line of infinite charge. The scalar potential equation was given in the form:

$$V(\mathbf r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int_L \frac{\rho'_l}{\lvert \mathbf r - \mathbf{r'} \rvert}\mathrm{d}l'. 
$$
Subbing in the variables used in this example:
\begin{gather*}
=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{r^2+z'^2}}dz'
\end{gather*}
Then a few steps later he goes from this:
$$\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}{-a+\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}\right)
$$

To this:
$$\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+{\frac{r^2}{a^2}}}+1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{r^2}{a^2}}-1}\right)
$$
Which I don't understand.

I'm fairly new to physics, so I'll be appreciative before I would be offended by dumbed down answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing physics related explains this, it's just an integral.

Comment: The step I'm confused about comes after the integration

Comment: After that it's just algebraic simplification, pull $a^2$ out of the root as $a$, then cancel the $a$'s.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pull $a^2$ out of the root as $a$"

Comment: Because $\sqrt{r^2 + a^2} = \sqrt{a^2 (\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1)}=a\sqrt{(\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1)}$

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was getting stuck on. Obviously a blind spot in my algebra.

Comment: of course, algebra is always a good skill to exercise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how to do the integral:
\begin{align}
I =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{r^2+z'^2}}dz' \tag{1}
\end{align}

This is carried by change varaible to triangular function:

[image]

\begin{align}
z' = & r \tan\theta; \,\,\, \text{ therefore } \,\, dz'= r\sec^2\theta.\\
\sqrt{r^2 + z'^2} = & r \sec\theta\\
z' = & \,\,\,a \,\,\,to\,\, \theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}; \\
z' = & -a \,\,to\,\, \theta = -\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}; 
\end{align}

Eq.(1) becomes:
\begin{align}
I =& \frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}^{\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}  \frac{r \sec^2\theta}{ r \sec\theta}   d\theta \\
=& \frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}^{\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}   \sec\theta   ​d\theta \\
=&\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}^{\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}   
 \frac{\sec\theta+ \tan\theta}{\sec\theta+ \tan\theta} \sec\theta   ​d\theta \\
=&\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}^{\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}   
 \frac{\sec^2\theta+ \sec\theta\tan\theta}{\sec\theta+ \tan\theta}    ​d\theta \\
=&\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{-\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}^{\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}   
 \frac{d\left( \sec\theta+ \tan\theta\right)}{\sec\theta+ \tan\theta} \\
=&\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \ln\left( \sec\theta+ \tan\theta\right)_{-\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}}^{\tan^{-1} \frac{a}{r}} .
\end{align}

Recalled that $\tan\theta_a = \frac{a}{r}$ , therefore $\sec\theta_a = \sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta_a} = \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}}$. And $\tan(-\theta_a) = -\frac{a}{r}$ an odd funciton, but $\sec(-\theta_a) = \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}}$ an even function.
\begin{align}
I =&\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left\{ \ln\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}}+ \frac{a}{r}\right) - \ln\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}} - \frac{a}{r}\right) \right\};\\
=&\frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left\{ \ln \frac{\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}}+ \frac{a}{r}\right)}{\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}} - \frac{a}{r}\right)} \right\}\\
=& \frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left\{ \ln \frac{\left( \sqrt{r^2+a^2}+ a\right)}{\left( \sqrt{r^2+a^2}- a\right)}\right\}\\
=& \frac{\eta}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left\{ \ln \frac{\left( \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1}+ 1\right)}{\left( \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1}- 1\right)}\right\}\\
\end{align}
In the last step, we divid bot denominator and numerator by factor $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I think I may have worded my question incorrectly though ( I just edited it). I was confused about the step after the integral.

Comment: So you did. Thank you very much! I appreciate your time.